# Error returned when running imdbpy2sql.py with MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sqlobject, imdbpy

I am working on getting IMDbPY installed and working and I have come to a point where I am working on pulling in all of the data from the flat (text) files in to a (MySQL) database.

When I run the appropriate command:

> imdbpy2sql.py -d /tmp/IMDB/ -u 'mysql://user:password@host/database'

I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2672, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 654, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Tempita>=0.4
```

I have tried using the `-o [sqlobject|sqlalchemy]` options as well but to no avail.

I am simply looking for a resolution or the cause for this error so that I can move forward. Has anyone seen this before or know of the cause?

My apologies if this is simple but `I am by no means a Python guru and in searching the internet for answers I have come up bust.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need the Tempita package. Install it using your distribution's package manager - e.g., for Ubuntu it would be "apt-get install python-tempita".

Comment: That solved the last portion that relates to Tempita, but the rest regarding `pkg_resources.py` still occur when I execute the file.

Comment: Can you post the new error message in its entirety? The pkg_resources.py file is a wrapper for calling in external packages.

Comment: This is the current error that I am recieving:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imdbpy2sql.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2672, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 654, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: decorator
`

Comment: Same as the original answer, but "decorator" is the package you need. So for Ubuntu, "apt-get install python-decorator". How did you install imdbpy? If you use your distribution's package, it takes care of this for you.