# I am trying loading Ipython notebook but got error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am loading IPtyhon Notebook. But I got the error. I am using python 2.7

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: decorator
```

Comment: Read the comments for a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8178455/707650): it appears your package manager doesn't fully do the right thing.

Comment: @Evert Thanks! I solved it upgrading python-decorator usinsg apm-get .

Comment: Good that it worked. Put it as answer and marked it solved for future readers/searchers. The comment in the linked question can't serve as a proper answer, since it actually answers another question (that was also posed in the comments).

Comment: @Evert Ok. Can I do it instead of you? You let me know the answer.